# Convert English numbers to Persian numbers for ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, farsi

I am working on a data visualization project using `ggplot2`.

All numbers obtained in the plot (Includes axis-x and axis-y and numbers inside the plot) are in English format like the below plot:

[image: example plot]

but I want the numbers in all plots to be Persian (e.g., ۲۰۱۵ instead of 2015).

I have many plots with different numbers. Can anyone help me to convert English numbers in the plot to Persian?

Comment: For those of us who aren't familiar with Persian but would nonetheless like to see if they can help out, would you mind linking to a page (for example wikipedia) where we can lookup the symbols for Persian numbers? I can imagine the `chartr()` function can help, but I don't know about the symbols enough to spell it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Approach 1 - replacing numbers

I found this function you wrote in the other question:

```r
convert_english_to_farsi <- function(x) {
  persian <- "\u0660\u0661\u0662\u0663\u0664\u0665\u0666\u0667\u0668\u0669\u06F0\u06F1\u06F2\u06F3\u06F4\u06F5\u06F6\u06F7\u06F8\u06F9"
  english <- "\U0030\U0031\U0032\U0033\U0034\U0035\U0036\U0037\U0038\U0039\U0030\U0031\U0032\U0033\U0034\U0035\U0036\U0037\U0038\U0039"
  return(chartr(english, persian, x))
}
```

This actually works quite well for me (I checked [here](http://www.saitak.com/number)):

```
convert_english_to_farsi(123456)
#> [1] "۱۲۳۴۵۶"
```

You can just use this function as the `labels` argument in most `scale_*` functions in `ggplot2`. For example if we want to change the y-axis labels of some plot (`economics` is included in `ggplot2` so this is reproducible):

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(economics, aes(x = date, y = unemploy)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = convert_english_to_farsi)
```

The highest number here is supposed to be 12,000 which translates to ۱۲۰۰۰, which looks correct.

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-02-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

### Approach 2 - replacing the font

Alternativly, you can use a different font that uses Persian numbers. I found one [here](https://github.com/MJZSoft/PersianPageNumber/raw/master/PersianPagerNumber-Regular.ttf). Download and install it in Windows. Then load it using the `extrafont` package:

```r
library(extrafont)
#> Registering fonts with R
font_import(
  path = "~/Fonts", # I placed only the downloaded ttf file here so only the relevant font is imported
  recursive = FALSE
)
```

You can check available fonts with:

```r
fonts()
#> [1] "Persian Pager Number"
```

Now change the font in your `ggplot2` theme like this:

```
ggplot(economics, aes(x = date, y = unemploy)) +
  geom_line() +
  theme_minimal(base_family = "Persian Pager Number")
```

[image]

Comment: I run this code on my system (Windows 10), But the format of the numbers obtained in the plot is not correct. It gives me numbers like this "€?CI\025\001". I do not know if the problem is with the R software or Windows

Comment: I fired up my Windows machine and realized you are right (the first answer was made using Linux). I added an alternative approach that worked on my Windows 10 machine. Hope it works now!

Comment: Do you have an idea about converting point to slash! because in Persian format, slash is used instead of point.
For example, 12.5 is read ۱۲/۵ in Persian format

Comment: You could write/adapt a simple function and use the `labels` argument as in approach 1. Or you can also directly use an anonymous function in `scale_y_continuous`: `scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) gsub(".", "/", x, fixed = TRUE))`

Comment: The `comma` function in `scales` also has an option for this: `scales::comma(12.5, accuracy = 0.1, decimal.mark = "/")`. Might work better than writing your own function as it handles rounding for plotting purposes well.