# convert english number to farsi in r

Tags: r, local, farsi

I want to replace English number with Farsi number. How can implement this?

0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9

convert to

۰-۱-۲-۳-۴-۵-۶-۷-۸-۹

for example 2658 Become ۲۶۵۸

Comment: Hi @rezgar. There are many nice and helpful people on SO and I am sure one of them can help you solve your issue. But instead of asking the same question [again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66030712/how-to-convert-english-number-to-persian-in-r) and [again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66017323/convert-all-english-numbers-to-persian-numer-for-ggplot), I think it is better to reply to comments from other users. I put a bounty on your first question so that it gets more attention. I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, The answers to these questions are useful for improving my results